# How to load resources from other JAR file

Tags: java, jar, classloader

I have troubles to make loading resources from other jars running. Here is the setup I have

```
resource.jar  # contains resources I want to load
`-res/hwview/file1

engine.jar    # my application which need resources
`-res/hwview/file2
```

Interesting thing is that using the code below I'm able to load `file2` (which is in the jar I run) but not the `file1`.

```
String dir = "res/hwview";
Enumeration<URL> e = getClass().getClassLoader().getResources(dir);
while(e.hasMoreElements()) {
    // prints only file1 from engine.jar 
    // (actually it's in classes directory because I run it from my IDE)
    System.out.println(e.nextElement());
}

[OUTPUT]
/path/to/my/project/SiHwViewUiModel/classes/res/hwview
```

So I thought maybe the jar was not picked up by the ClassLoader so I printed what was loaded

```
ClassLoader cl = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
URL[] urls = ((URLClassLoader)cl).getURLs();
for(URL url: urls){
    System.out.println(url.getFile());
}

[OUTPUT]
/path/to/my/project/SiHwViewUiModel/classes/
/path/to/my/project/Resources/deploy/resources.jar
... and other not so important jars
```

Any ideas?
Thanks for any help!

Comment: [Duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14147940/loading-a-resource-from-a-jar-within-a-jar)?

Comment: @hd1 not sure, I don't have any inner jar

Comment: Same principle, sir, you must load the Class object corresponding to that resource, using Class.forName(class-within-resource-jar) and then you can do what you wish with it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution. The problem with `getResources()` method and similar is that thay cannot be given a directory but only a particular file. This means that if I want to search in the whole classpath for a particular structure I need to create *marker* file in base directories.

**Example:** I want to get to `my/path` directory -> create `marker.info` (name does not matter) file and then search for it.

```
resources.jar
`- my/path/
   |- my/directories
   `- marker.info

resources2.jar
`- my/path/
   |- my/other/directories
   `- marker.info

# search
Enumeration<URL> urls = getClass().getClassLoader().getResources("my/path/marker.info"); 

# print
print(urls);
/path/to/resources.jar!/my/path/marker.info
/path/to/resources2.jar!/my/path/marker.info
```

Answer (score 1):

If the JAR files are on the classpath, you don't need to do anything special. The resources will be found.

If they aren't on the classpath, you need to create a [`URLClassLoader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLClassLoader.html) and use its `getResource()` method.

Comment: I used URLClassLoader, i cannot get the InputStream.
URL url = new URL( "file", null, "/home/solr-cell-4.8.0-test.jar" );
URLClassLoader urlClassLoader = new URLClassLoader( new URL[] { url } );

InputStream input = urlClassLoader.getResourceAsStream(classAsPath);
BufferedReader dis = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));

Comment: something like "/META-INF/NOTICE.txt"

Comment: 'Something like' isn't much use to anybody.

Comment: You are right. I use:
String classAsPath = "/org/apache/MANIFEST.MF";
I put a MANIFEST.MF file under that package.

Answer (score 0):

In Spring, it can load xml file from all the jar files in the classpath:

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
        "classpath*:**/applicationContext*.xml");
```

You can check the Spring source to see how Spring achieve that.

Comment: I need to do this without Spring

Answer (score -2):

```
public final class JarResource
{
private String jarFileName;
private Map<String, Long> hashSizes = new HashMap<String, Long>();
private Map<String, Object> hashJarContents = new HashMap<String, Object>();

public JarResource(String jarFileName) throws Exception
{
    this.jarFileName = jarFileName;
    ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(this.jarFileName);

    Enumeration<ZipEntry> e = (Enumeration<ZipEntry>) zipFile.entries();
    while (e.hasMoreElements())
    {
        ZipEntry zipEntry = e.nextElement();
        if(!zipEntry.isDirectory())
        {
            hashSizes.put(getSimpleName(zipEntry.getName()), zipEntry.getSize());
        }
    }
    zipFile.close();

    // extract resources and put them into the hashMap.
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(jarFileName);
    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
    ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(bis);
    ZipEntry ze = null;

    while ((ze = zis.getNextEntry()) != null)
    {
        if (ze.isDirectory())
        {
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            long size = (int) ze.getSize();
            // -1 means unknown size.
            if (size == -1)
            {
                size = hashSizes.get(ze.getName());
            }

            byte[] b = new byte[(int) size];
            int rb = 0;
            int chunk = 0;
            while (((int) size - rb) > 0)
            {
                chunk = zis.read(b, rb, (int) size - rb);
                if (chunk == -1)
                {
                    break;
                }
                rb += chunk;
            }

            hashJarContents.put(ze.getName(), b);
        }
    }
    zis.close();
}

public byte[] getResource(String name)
{
    return (byte[]) hashJarContents.get(name);
}

private String getSimpleName(String entryName)
{
    // Remove ".jar" extension
    int index = entryName.indexOf("/");
    String fileNameWithoutExt = entryName.substring(index, entryName.length());

    return fileNameWithoutExt;
}
}
```

Then use this class to load your resource:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    JarResource jr = new JarResource("/home/mjiang/Downloads/solr-4.8.0/dist/solr-cell-4.8.0-test.jar");
    byte[] resource = jr.getResource("/META-INF/NOTICE.txt");

    InputStream input = new ByteInputStream(resource, resource.length);

    BufferedReader dis = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));

    String line = "";
    while((line = dis.readLine()) != null)
    {
        System.out.println(line);
    }

    dis.close();
}
```

Comment: This reads the JAR file twice, and loads the entire contents of the JAR file into memory. It isn't actually necessary to waste time and space on this epic scale.

Comment: You are right. I should skip loading any class files which will greatly reduce the time and space.

Comment: You should skip loading everything until something is actually requested. You should provide it as a ClassLoader. In which case you would be merely duplicating URLClassLoader.

Comment: It is correct that URLClassLoader already does all this, and better.